# How to use editable table in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to use editable table in angular but didnt found any good articles,can anyone suggest some.Thanks.
I tried this,

```
<ng-table [config]="config.sorting"
          (tableChanged)="onChangeTable(config)" 
          [rows]="rows" [columns]="columns" >
</ng-table>
```

This is my columns and rows,

```
 rows: Array<any> = [];
  columns: Array<any> = [
    {title: 'Name', name: 'accountname'},
    {title: 'Email', name: 'email', sort: false},
    {title: 'Phone', name: 'phone', sort: 'asc'},
  ];
```

but i want edit and delete buttons on each column.How can i get that?

Comment: Show code. What have you tried and what's the error.

Comment: Sefa,edited my code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add buttons to columns to ng2-table in angular 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40343134/how-to-add-buttons-to-columns-to-ng2-table-in-angular-2) (same op)

Answer (score 2):

If you want a good datatable plugin for angular2 i can recommend PrimeNG, they have a datatable that we are using in our projects that are really good with support for editable, sorting, filtering. PrimeNG is a collection of rich UI components for Angular 2. 
http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatableeditable

[image]

Comment: PrimeNG is available at npm, if you have an existing application run the following command to download it to your project.


npm install primeng --save

Comment: is it necessary to install primeUI for primeng to run? i did install it the DataTable or any other control does not run successfully?

Comment: you only need to install PrimeNG to use the controlls. Use following NPM command.
npm install primeng --save

Answer (score 2):

can you take a look at this [link](https://plnkr.co/edit/SRLYoX5chNYJIpZ4iqsG?p=preview), its a good example using directives!

this is the directive that he used:

```
@Directive({
selector: '[contenteditableModel]'
})
export class ContenteditableModelDirective implements OnChanges {

  @Input('contenteditableModel')
  public model: any;

  @Output('contenteditableModelChange')
  public update = new EventEmitter();

  private _lastViewModel: any;

  constructor(private elRef: ElementRef) {}

  public ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
     if(this._lastViewModel !== changes['model'].currentValue){
        this._lastViewModel = this.model;
        this._refreshView();
     }
  }

  @HostListener('blur')
  public onBlur() {
    var value = this.elRef.nativeElement.innerText;
    this._lastViewModel = value;
    this.update.emit(value);
  }

  private _refreshView() {
    this.elRef.nativeElement.innerText = this.model;
  }
}
```

and this is how to use it:

```
<h2 contenteditable="true" [(contenteditableModel)]="text"></h2>
```